# Firefox Webextension: capture all tabs

Tags: javascript, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a `webextension` for `firefox` and need to capture all tabs. I use the following code but `capture` is `undefined`:

```
var tabResults = [];

for (let tab of tabs) {
    var tabImage;
    var capturing = browser.tabs.captureTab(tab.id);
    capturing.then(function(imageUri){
        return imageUri;
    }).then(imageUri => {
        tabImage = imageUri;
    });

    tabResults.push({
        title: tab.title,
        fav: tab.favIconUrl,
        pinned: tab.pinned,
        capture: imageUri
    });
}
```

Actually I confused how promises work, because `captureTab` return an `promise` and I don't know how to get captured image from a `promise` inside a loop

Comment: The `tabResults.push` call happens before this statement `tabImage = imageUri;`. Function passed as a parameter to `then` are run async. You can learn more about how promises work from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

push your data inside `then` function. As [captureTab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureTab) is asynchronous function

```
var tabResults = [];

for (let tab of tabs) {
  var tabImage;
  var capturing = browser.tabs.captureTab(tab.id);
  capturing.then(function(imageUri) {
    tabResults.push({
      title: tab.title,
      fav: tab.favIconUrl,
      pinned: tab.pinned,
      capture: imageUri
    })
  });
}
```